Where should paclen setting come from in Linux ax.25?
On Linux, in the /etc/ax25/axports file, the parameters for an ax.25 interface include:

name
callsign
speed
paclen
window
description

When you create a new ax.25 interface (e.g. by running kissattach), it sets the MTU of the interface to the paclen value...but the paclen value in the kernel control block (struct ax25_cb) still defaults to 256. It's this internal value that gets used by new connections, etc, and any client code that attempts to use SIOCAX25GETINFO to the paclen will see this default value rather than the value set in /etc/ax25/axports.
Should kissattach also set the paclen value in the kernel along with the MTU? Should the interface MTU and paclen always be equal?
